# How can I download an Azure Artifact (not build artifact) in a Azure Pipeline (YAML)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-yaml-pipelines

Is there a way to download an Azure Artifact into a Azure Pipeline? I see there's way to download a Build Artifact, however I am not looking for this. I push an Azure Artifact and need it in my pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to download an Azure Artifact into a Azure Pipeline?

Yes. You can use the [Download Package task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-package?view=azure-devops) to download the packages in Azure Artifacts.

Here is an example:

```
- task: DownloadPackage@1
  inputs:
    packageType: 'nuget'
    feed: 'feedname'
    view: 'release'
    definition: 'packagename'
    version: version'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```